# How to filter records from analytical functions and return rows based on the condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Let's say we have the below table as items with below columns

```
order_name    price    price_date
cheese          10     10/21/2022
cheese          15     10/22/2022
cheese          12     10/23/2022
cake            10     10/22/2022
cake            15     10/23/2022
banana          10     10/25/2022
banana          12     10/26/2022
banana          15     10/27/2022
```

Note (price_date in (MM/DD/YYYY) format, Now I want the result as below where in it returns only two rows

```
cake    15  10/23/2022
banana  15  10/27/2022
```

these are the items for which price is increasing everyday, whereas for cheese on 10/23/2022 it's price has decreased from the previous day 15 --> 12 on 10/23/2022 ,so I don't want cheese as part of the returned data ? Can somebody help me how to write a SQL query for this ?

Explained as above need only two rows as a result (cake and banana)

Comment: Threre are multiple parts that this task can be split into: 1) calculate price changes between two dates. 2) identify existence of different directions of price changes per product.  3) calculate final price and date. 4) filter out products that have two directions of price change. What exact part is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to compare prices between two rows per order name (and set the flag if price drops); sort data per order name by date in descending order. Finally, return orders that don't have any flags and rank as the highest.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (order_name, price, price_date) as
  2    (select 'cheese', 10, date '2022-10-21' from dual union all
  3     select 'cheese', 15, date '2022-10-22' from dual union all
  4     select 'cheese', 12, date '2022-10-23' from dual union all
  5     select 'cake'  , 10, date '2022-10-22' from dual union all
  6     select 'cake'  , 15, date '2022-10-23' from dual union all
  7     select 'banana', 10, date '2022-10-25' from dual union all
  8     select 'banana', 12, date '2022-10-26' from dual union all
  9     select 'banana', 15, date '2022-10-27' from dual
 10    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
 11  temp as
 12    (select t.*,
 13       case when lag(price) over (partition by order_name order by price_date) > price then 'x'
 14            else null
 15       end flag,
 16       row_number() over (partition by order_name order by price_date desc) rn
 17     from test t
 18    )
 19  select a.order_name, a.price, a.price_date
 20  from temp a
 21  where not exists (select null
 22                    from temp b
 23                    where b.order_name = a.order_name
 24                      and b.flag = 'x'
 25                   )
 26    and a.rn = 1;

ORDER_      PRICE PRICE_DATE
------ ---------- ----------
cake           15 10/23/2022
banana         15 10/27/2022

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Window function with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` condition as follows:

```
SELECT
    ORDER_NAME,
    MAX(PRICE) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY PRICE_DATE) AS PRICE
  FROM
    (  SELECT
            ORDER_NAME, PRICE, PRICE_DATE,
            CASE WHEN LAG(PRICE) OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER_NAME ORDER BY PRICE_DATE) > PRICE THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS PREV_PRICE_FLAG
          FROM YOUR_TABLE
    ) T
 GROUP BY ORDER_NAME
HAVING SUM(PREV_PRICE_FLAG) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, arrange your data according to price_date and price separately using window function `row_number()` , then pick out only the rows where the order matches. Lastly, return the names where the total number of rows matches the total number of matching rows:

```
select order_name, max(price_date) as price_date
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by order_name order by price_date) rn_bydate,
            row_number() over (partition by order_name order by price) rn_byprice,
            count(*) over (partition by order_name) as cnt
  from mytable 
) s
where rn_bydate = rn_byprice
group by order_name
having count(*) = max(cnt);
```

Results :

```
order_name  price_date
banana      2022-10-27
cake        2022-10-23
```

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_NAME
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY order_name
         ORDER BY price_date
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN (^ {- increasing+ -} final_row $)
         DEFINE increasing AS NEXT(price) > price
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (order_name, price, price_date) AS
SELECT 'cheese', 10, DATE '2022-10-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'cheese', 15, DATE '2022-10-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'cheese', 12, DATE '2022-10-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'cake',   10, DATE '2022-10-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'cake',   15, DATE '2022-10-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'banana', 10, DATE '2022-10-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'banana', 12, DATE '2022-10-26' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'banana', 15, DATE '2022-10-27' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ORDER_NAME | PRICE_DATE | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| banana | 2022-10-27 00:00:00 | 15 |
| cake | 2022-10-23 00:00:00 | 15 |

Answer (score 0):

Mark trend for raise as 1 otherwise 0. Aggregate and select rows Having Min(trend) = 1:

```sql
Select  ORDER_NAME, Max(PRICE) "PRICE", Max(PRICE_DATE) "PRICE_DATE"
From    ( Select  test.*, Case When PRICE > Nvl(LAG(PRICE) Over(Partition By ORDER_NAME Order By PRICE_DATE), 1) Then 1 
                          Else 0 End "TREND"
          From    test )
Group By ORDER_NAME
Having Min(TREND) = 1
/*  R e s u l t : 
ORDER_NAME      PRICE PRICE_DATE
---------- ---------- ----------
cake               15 23.10.22
banana             15 27.10.22    */
```